# Sections do not maintain at the same level

Tags: html, css

I am new in HTML/CSS and I'm trying to build a simple website. 
my code in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <title>  Motors </title>
 <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
 <link href="style.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/CSS" />
</head>
<body>
 <header>
    <h1 id="cmpName">
        MOTORS
    </h1>
    <nav>
        <ul id = "navigation">
            <li> <a href="#"> HOME  </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> CATALOGUE </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> ACHIVEMENTS </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> ABOUT US </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> CONTACT </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id = "slideDiv">
        <img class="slideImg" src="http://eskipaper.com/images/toyota-wallpaper-2.jpg" />
        <img class="slideImg" src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/2013_lamborghini_aventador_lp700_4-wide.jpg"/> 
        <img class="slideImg" src="https://images7.alphacoders.com/318/318873.jpg"/> 
        <img class="slideImg" src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/ferrari_red_cars_sport_95424_3840x2400.jpg"/> 
    </div>
</header>
<section id="mainContent">
    <section class="oneNews">
        <h3 class = "newsHeader"> New Headquarters </h3> 
        <img src="http://acdn.architizer.com/thumbnails-PRODUCTION/ee/87/ee87914abbec5ba91890ea35110e7a0b.jpg" class = "newsImg"/>
        <p class="newsDscr"> The headquarters for Spanish energy utility provider Endesa fuses innovative workplace design with a progressive environmental program. </p>
    </section>

    <section class="oneNews">
        <h3 class = "newsHeader"> Shchumacher Wins </h3> 
        <img src="https://formula1.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/season2011_race1_wallpapers_01_1280x1024.jpg" class = "newsImg"/>
        <p class="newsDscr"> In winning the Drivers' Championship he equalled the record set by Juan Manuel Fangio of five World Championships. Ferrari won 15 out of 17 races, and Schumacher won the title with six races remaining in the season. </p>
    </section>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata');



html,body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #708ebf;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
header {
 width: 900px;
 background-color: #0543a8;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 padding-top: 0;
}
#cmpName {

 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
 font-size: 60px;
 margin: 0;
}
nav {
 margin: 0;
}
#navigation {
 background-color: #0d52c1;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;

}
#navigation li {
 list-style-type: none;
 font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 30px;
 margin-left: 19px;
 margin-right: 19px;
 color: black;
}
#slideDiv{
 width: 900px;
 height: 450px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
 right: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
.slideImg {
 width: 900px;
 height: 450px;
 display: inline;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 5px;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
#mainContent {
 width: 900px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border: solid;
 padding: 0;

}
.oneNews {
 display: inline-block;
 border: solid;
 margin: 10px;
 width: 270px;
 height: 500px;
 padding: 0;
}
.newsImg {
 width: 270px;
 height: 150px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;

}
.newsDscr {
 width: 270px;
 text-align: center;
 height: 120px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.newsHeader {
 width: 270px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

At the bottom of the page, as you see there are two sections (class = "oneNews") but depending on their description, they align differently and are not maintaining the same level.
Any suggestions why?
P.S I could not find any questions containing same meaning, but if there is one please link and I'll delete this question.

Comment: you should try bootstrap [link] (http://getbootstrap.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add vertical  align to your class. Try this:

```
.oneNews {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 270px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: This would have been a much better answer if it explained what went wrong and how this addition solves it.

Comment: @B. Desai It worked and I'm thankful for that but, I had almost same code (different but it was set of many little sections) and I never used vertical-align property but they were fine, they aligned at the same level despite the text. Can you explain why this happened? why did bigger text made sections go up/down ?

Comment: Its because you are using `display: inline-block;` If you are change it to `float:left` then no need to add `vertical-align: top;`. try it